# Recursive grep in perl

Tags: perl, recursion, grep, file-handling

I am new to perl. I have a directory structure. In each directory, I have a log file. I want to grep pattern from that file and do post processing. Right now I am grepping the pattern from those files using unix grep and putting into text file and reading that text file to do post processing, But I want to automate task of reading each file and grepping pattern from that file. In the code below the `mdp_cgdis_1102.txt` have grepped pattern from directories. I would really appreciate any help

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, 'mdp_cgdis_1102.txt' or die "Cannot open file $!";

my @array = <FILE>;
my @arr;
my @brr;

foreach my  $i (@array){
@arr = split (/\//, $i);
@brr = split (/\:/, $i);
print " $arr[0] ---  $brr[2]";
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample directory structure and an example of the string you want to grep?

Comment: Might be a job for `File::Find`. Hard to say without more information what you're doing though.

Comment: So the text file has the output from unix grep, and you want to use that output?

Comment: Some sample of the output text file will be required.

Comment: Do you need to automate the process of building the file-list, as the post title may imply, or the process of scanning (known) files for patterns, as you specifically say in the post? Or ... both?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. The grepped lines from the log file  looks like this _italic_ **bold** 'wvitunit/cgen/reports/wvitunit.mdp.rpt:all_ff_cge_ur' and directory structutre is abcunit/cgen/reports/abcunit.mdp.rpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me which part of the process needs automating. I'll go by "*want to automate reading each file and grepping pattern from that file*,"  whereby you presumably already have a list of files.  If you actually need to build the file list as well see the added code below.

One way: pull all patterns from each file and store that in a hash (filename => arrayref-with-patterns)

```
my %file_pattern;
foreach my $file (@filelist) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    $file_pattern{$file} = [ grep { /$pattern/ } <$fh> ];
    close $fh;
}
```

The `[ ]` takes a reference to the list returned by `grep`, ie. constructs an "anonymous array", and that (reference) is assigned as a value to the `$file` key.

Now you can process your patterns, per log file

```
foreach my $filename (sort keys %file_pattern) {
    print "Processing log $filename.\n";
    my @patterns = @{$file_pattern{$filename}};
    # Process the list of patterns in this log file
}
```

**ADDED**

In order to build the list of files `@filelist` used above, from a known list of directories, use core [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)
 module which recursively scans supplied directories and applies supplied subroutines

```
use File::Find;
find( { wanted => \&process_logs, preprocess => \&select_logs }, @dir_list);
```

Your subroutine `process_logs()` is applied to each file/directory that passed preprocessing by the second sub, with its name available as `$File::Find::name`, and in it you can either populate the hash with patterns-per-log as shown above, or run complete processing as needed.

Your subroutine `select_logs()` contains code to filter log files from all files in each directory, that `File::Find` would normally processes, so that `process_file()` only gets the log files.

Another way would be to use the other invocation

```
find(\&process_all, @dir_list);
```

where now the sub `process_all()` is applied to all entries (files and directories) found and thus this sub itself needs to ensure that it only processes the log files. See linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of

```
find ... -name '*.txt' -type f -exec grep ... {} +
```

is

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my $base_dir_qfn = ...;
my $re = qr/.../;

my @log_qfns =
   File::Find::Rule
   ->name(qr/\..txt\z/)
   ->file
   ->in($base_dir_qfn);

my $success = 1;
for my $log_qfn (@log_qfns) {
   open(my $fh, '<', $log_qfn)
      or do {
         $success = 0;
         warn("Can't open log file \"$log_qfn\": $!\n);
         next;
      };

   while (<$fh>) {
      print if /$re/;
   }
}

exit(1) if !$success;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `File::Find` to traverse the directory.

In a loop go through all the logfiles:

1. Open the file
2. read it line by line
3. For each line, do a regular expression match (
       `if ($line =~ /pattern/)` ) or use 
   `if (index($line, $searchterm) >= 0)` if you are looking for a certain static string.
4. If you find a match, print the line.
5. close the file

I hope that gives you enough pointers to get started. You will learn more if you find out how to do each of these steps in Perl by yourself (I pointed out the hard ones).